# Android virtual device taking too much time to load OS

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new in android app development. when I installed all the required packages for development I ran the emulator and navigated through the Android OS. That means the emulator was installed perfectly. But when I tried to run my first app, the emulator is taking too much time to load OS. I waited for about 15 minutes but it was still loading and loading. Then I closed it. Then I also tried to run it from device manager but it also could not load the OS. So how can I solve this problem?

In my emulator, the "snapshot" option is enabled.

Comment: Could you give us some infos on your pc configuration (RAM, processor, OS ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have enabled snapshots. If you enabled it then you can be trying to open a incorrectly saved snapshot. If so, while starting the emulator with launch options, uncheck launch from startup.

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Android Virtual device manager" , select the AVD and click edit , select the device        "HVGA", click ok . Now Run your project. The emulator will come up in 2-3 minutes.